# How to match a paragraph against phrases in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

My objective is to use ElasticSearch to find what indexed phrases can be found inside the paragraph being queried.

I've tried using percolate search, but I wasn't able to refine it to be a 100% match. Sadly, ElasticSearch docs are not clear enough.

My Indexed documents:

- must be faster than 50mph
- must jump higher than a tree
- be able to stand on two feet

My query:

> "We are looking for an animal that must be able to stand on two feet, also must jump higher than a tree, and should be faster than 40mph, and has white and red stripes with wings"

What results I expect (exact matches, case insensitive):

- be able to stand on two feet
- must jump higher than a tree

What results I am getting (partial matches):

- be able to stand on two feet
- must jump higher than a tree
- must **be faster than** 50mph

Comment: What query are you using? Can you provide the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I wasn't able to refine it to be a 100% match

It seems you need to use a [full-text query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) like [Match Phrase Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html). From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html):

> The high-level full text queries are usually used for running full text queries on full text fields like the body of an email.

Comment: Yes, this is it! The docs are not very clear, but you can store different types of query on the percolator index and they have a direct impact on the reverse search. And for anyone that comes across this in the future, this is valid for ES 6.5

Answer (score 1):

As suggested already, you should give [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) a try.

Your query should look something like.

```
GET <indexname>/_search
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Sentence": "be able to stand on two feet"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Sentence": "must jump higher than a tree"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> P.S.: You should be providing match_phrases in a sequence as it is
>   there in the field.

Comment: Yes, this is it! The docs are not very clear, but you can store different types of query on the percolator index and they have a direct impact on the reverse search. And for anyone that comes across this in the future, this is valid for ES 6.5